How to integrate a function of two complex variables where a pole may lie on a branch cut?
I have a function of two variables of the form
$$ G(u,v) = \frac{f(u)g(v)}{(u^2-v^2) \sqrt{v^2-1}}$$
where $f(u), g(v)$ are analytic in $u$ and $v$. I want to perform an inverse Laplace transform in both variables using a Bromwich inversion. I think the correct way to do this is to fix one variable, perform the inversion on the other variable, then do another inversion on what is left over.
If I do the inversion on $u$ first (fixing $v$), there seems to be no problem: there are poles at $u = \pm v$, so I choose a constant $C > |Re(v)|$, and get a new function
$$G(v) = \int_{C-i\infty}^{C+i\infty} \frac{du}{2\pi i} G(u,v) e^{su}$$
which I can compute by "closing the contour on the left" and applying the residue theorem:
$$G'(s,v) = \frac{f(v)g(v)e^{sv} - f(-v)g(v) e^{-sv}}{2v \sqrt{v^2-1}} .$$
I can then happily apply the Bromwich inversion on this new function to get a real integral by dealing with the branch cut. Choosing the cut on $[-1,1]$, I get
$$G''(s,t) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-1}^{1} dx \frac{f(x)g(x) e^{sx} - f(-x)g(x) e^{-sx}}
{2x\sqrt{1-x^2}} e^{tx}$$
However, if I instead integrate $v$ first (fixing $u$), I see a problem: since $u$ is arbitrary, I can fix it to be on whatever branch cut I choose for the square root, or I can fix it to not be on the branch cut. In the case that it is on the branch cut, according to this post it seems I just need to treat the branch cut with a principal value integral. In that case, I get $G''(s,t)$ as above (as a principal value integral, but this does not matter in my case).
In the other case, where $u$ is not on the branch cut, upon doing the first Bromwich inversion I get contributions from the branch cut and from the poles at $v = \pm u$:
$$G_1(u,t) = \frac{-(f(u)g(u) e^{tu} + f(u)g(-u) e^{-tu})}{2u\sqrt{u^2-1}} + (\text{terms from branch cut}) .$$
The terms from the branch cut are the same as when $u$ is on the branch cut. This extra term does not vanish as $u$ approaches the branch cut, so it seems that a new non-analyticity may have been introduced.
Does the order of integration matter? What is the correct way to deal with this pole-that-may-be-on-a-branch-cut?
